# node.js express : how make a folder picker?

Tags: node.js, express, dialog, picker

I found easily how to make a folder picker for electron in node.js but 
I don't find how to do this in express.

In express we have a lot of permissions thanks to node, so I think this is probably possible.

Do you know how to make a folder picker in express please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Electron Dialogs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog)

Here's an example:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))
```

Comment: I know the feature might not have been present or well documented at the time of asking but I'm doing it for r̶e̶p̶u̶t̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶  people who came here via a search